# What is search operator for directories in Windows 7 analogous to file:

Tags: windows-7

I would like to only find directories with a certain name, how do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Append `type:folder` to your query.

Comment: Do I still use file:Name and then type:folder or just Name type:folder?

Comment: Just <name> type:folder should work.